# segmentation fault on fread

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles, fread

I keep getting a segmentation fault when I attempt to use fread. The file exists and is not empty.

```
NodePtr lnodePtr = NULL;
NodePtr fnodePtr = NULL;
NodePtr idnodePtr = NULL;
NodePtr gnodePtr = NULL;

printf("1b\n");
FILE *studentData = malloc(sizeof(FILE));
printf("2b\n");
int numRecords = 0;
printf("3b\n");
SREC student;

printf("4b\n");
if (fopen("database", "rb") != NULL)
{
    printf("5b\n");
    while (fread (&student, sizeof(SREC), 1, studentData) == 1)//happens here
    {
        printf("6b\n");
        insert (&lnodePtr, student, 1);
        insert (&fnodePtr, student, 2);
        insert (&idnodePtr, student, 3);
        insert (&gnodePtr, student, 4);
        printf("7b\n");
        numRecords++;
    }
}
printf("8b\n");
```

I've also tried to changed it to this and still gives me a segmentation fault

```
NodePtr lnodePtr = NULL;
NodePtr fnodePtr = NULL;
NodePtr idnodePtr = NULL;
NodePtr gnodePtr = NULL;

printf("1b\n");
FILE *studentData = malloc(sizeof(FILE));
printf("2b\n");
int numRecords = 0;
printf("3b\n");
SREC *student = malloc(sizeof(SREC));

printf("4b\n");
if (fopen("database", "rb") != NULL)
{
    printf("5b\n");
    while (fread (student, sizeof(SREC), 1, studentData) == 1)//happens here
    {
        printf("6b\n");
        insert (&lnodePtr, *student, 1);
        insert (&fnodePtr, *student, 2);
        insert (&idnodePtr, *student, 3);
        insert (&gnodePtr, *student, 4);
        printf("7b\n");
        numRecords++;
    }
}
printf("8b\n");
```

Here's the structures I'm using:

```
typedef struct student {
    char lname[ 10 ], initial, fname[ 10 ];
    unsigned long SID;
    float GPA;
} SREC;

typedef struct node {
    SREC s;
    struct node *nextPtr;
} Node;

typedef Node *NodePtr;
```

Also am I reading from the binary file correctly? I'm trying to read a bunch of SREC's in and add them into linked lists and I'm super new to reading and writing to binary files in C.

Edit: Here's how I wrote to the file idk if this would be messing with anything:

```
        printf("begin\n");
        studentData = fopen("database", "wb");
        while(lnodePtr != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(&(lnodePtr->s), sizeof(SREC), 1, studentData);
            lnodePtr = lnodePtr->nextPtr;
        }
        printf("end\n");
```

Edit2: SOLVED! Thanks guys

Comment: yes on tutorials point and I think I'm using the correct parameters

Comment: `FILE *studentData = malloc(sizeof(FILE));` --> `FILE *studentData;`...`fopen("database", "rb")` --> `(studentData = fopen("database", "rb"))`

Comment: [man fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread): "Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a FILE pointer".

Comment: `File *studentData = fopen("database","rb");`